# Saving object that contains an array of objects

Tags: java, android-studio, serialization, local-storage, sharedpreferences

Let's say I have an object. And one of the characteristics of that on object is that it contains an array of objects different from itself

Now, I want to save that container as well as all the objects inside of it. Would Serializing and saving that object, into internal storage or sharedPreferences, also save all of the contained objects(that are also serializable), or is that array just an array of references?

The context is my application has arrays of simple objects, that themselves contain arrays of simple objects. And I need to make sure that their data remains persistent and consistent.

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, that the contained objects will be saved? Or yes, that the array is just references?

Comment: Yes, the objects and object graph.  See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/object-graph-in-java-serialization#:~:text=Object%20Graph%20in%20Java%20Serialization%20Java%20Server%20Side,object%20reference%20will%20be%20serialized%20by%20the%20JVM.